# MySQL REGEXP does not work properly with Russian chars

Tags: mysql, regex

`SELECT 'Hello' REGEXP '^[^aeiouAEIOU][A-Za-z]*$' -> 1`

`SELECT 'Привет' REGEXP '^[^аеиоуыэюяАЕИОУЫЭЮЯ][А-Яа-я]*$' -> 0` - it must return 1.

Comment: Sounds more like a bug to issue with Oracle than a question.

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL's REGEXP only works with *bytes*.**  Russian characters are each 2 bytes.

For **limiting to Cyrillic**, this seems to be correct:

```
SELECT HEX('Привет') REGEXP '^((D0|D1)..)+$'; -- > 1
```

(I'll get to the issue of avoiding leading vowels in a minute.)

**To explain:**

- All Russian characters are 2 bytes, the first byte being hex `D0` or `D1`.  (There may be non-Russian characters starting that way; I'm ignoring that problem.)
- `(...|...)` - `|` means 'OR'.
- `..` matches a 2-byte hex, saying that the second byte can be anything (this is overkill but may not hurt).
- `(...)+` - The plus means one or more occurrence.
- The `^` and `$` 'anchor' the regexp to encompass the entire string.

Back to the **no-leading-vowel** issue.  Now we need to play some painful games to list the vowels; their HEX seem to be

```
D0, followed by any of B0 B5 B8 BE
                       90 95 98 9E, or 
D1, followed by any of 83 8B 8D 8E 8F
                       A3 AB AD AE AF
```

Example:  `select hex('э');` --> `D18D`.

Putting it all together will be messy because MySQL does not have the `(?` tools to say "not".  So, I will start by testing *for* a leading vowel:

```
SELECT HEX('Привет')
REGEXP '^(D0(B0|B5|B8|BE|90|95|98|9E))|(D1(83|8B|8D|8E|8F|A3|AB|AD|AE|AF))'
```

correctly fails.

**Now to put things together:**

```
SELECT NOT HEX('Привет')
REGEXP '^(D0(B0|B5|B8|BE|90|95|98|9E))|(D1(83|8B|8D|8E|8F|A3|AB|AD|AE|AF))'
AND        HEX('Привет')
REGEXP '^((D0|D1)..)+$';
```

The first part check for `NOT` a leading vowel; the second part check for all characters being Russian.

That test case works, and `'э'` came back with `0`, but I may have goofed somewhere.

(That was a challenge.)

Comment: This should be adaptable to other languages, but on a case-by-case basis.